# Jquery refresh issue forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit, refresh

I use a HTML form and a small snippet of jquery via onclick to display a loading spinner. However the spinner only shows for a second then closes instantly. I assume this is because of the post back of the page during the submit process.

Ive had a poke around with onclick and onsubmit but to no avail.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function LoadIcon() {

$("#form1").click(function(){
 $('#loading').html("Loading please wait"); 
});
}
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">   
<input name="button" onclick="LoadIcon()" id="button" type="submit"  value="Search Now">
</form>

<div id='loading'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the the page to submit and the loading spinner to remain displayed as per this code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>**[1]**</sup> Don't use event inside a function with `onclick` .. you can choose between  **->** The action in a function and `onclick` OR **->** Use the event like the example below

<sup>**[2]**</sup> Wrap the event in `$(function(){....})` to run the code when the document is ready

<sup>**[3]**</sup> With forms use `submit` not `click`

<sup>**[4]**</sup> Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default redirect of the form

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//function LoadIcon() {
$(function(){
  $("#form1").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $('#loading').html("Loading please wait"); 
  });
});
//}
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">   
<input name="button" id="button" type="submit"  value="Search Now">
</form>

<div id='loading'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>**[Finally]**</sup> If you have inputs in a form you may need to use `ajax`